How to handle changing /dev/snd device names using alsa in a permanent container?
I am running a permanent container (based on Ubuntu 22.04 from docker.hub) on a host with Ubuntu 24.04. To be able to play audio I installed alsa-utils in the container and configured the defaults via /etc/asound.conf:
defaults.pcm.!card Generic_1
defaults.ctl.!card Generic_1
defaults.pcm.!device 0
defaults.ctl.!device 0

It works fine until the sound devices in /dev/snd are changing names (e.g. during a restart of the host machine after sound devices were unplugged). Then starting the container fails with the following error:
Error: unable to start container "<container-ID>": crun: cannot stat `/dev/snd/controlC3`: No such file or directory: OCI runtime attempted to invoke a command that was not found
Error: can only create exec sessions on running containers: container state improper

I think the problem is, that the system in the container is never restarted, so alsa does not "scan" for the new device names in /dev/snd but expects the known ones to be there when I start the container.
I followed this guide and thought using alsa was the easiest solution. (I cannot have the same user on the container as on the host.)
I tried to start the container again after the device names in /dev/snd changed and expected the container to start.
I really appreciate any hint or help. Thanks
